# Ethernet and Wi-Fi simultaneously, help configuring

Tags: networking, wireless, streaming

I'm trying to connect my Ubuntu laptop to two separate routers.

1. Local Wi-Fi connection - to which is connected one device that streams video via UDP unicast to my laptops IP local address, for 
   example 192.168.6.11
2. Internet Ethernet Connection - 2nd router that provides Internet connection so that I can live stream via OBS etc.

I've got both networks working, but with some hiccups, or for example OBS failing to connect (stream).

I could surf the Internet.

My configs:

1. Network 1, Local: manual IP, 192.168.6.11, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.6.1
   ROUTES: 224.0.0.0, 240.0.0.0 - **ticked**  "Use this connection only for resources on its network" (not sure this is the correct approach...?)
2. Network 2, Internet Ethernet: DHCP
   ROUTES: 224.0.0.0, 240.0.0.0 - **NOT!** ticked  "Use this connection only for resources on its network" (not sure this is the correct approach...?)

Also, on both routers I've set "IGMP snooping" because of UDP unicast.

What else to do?

As when it works I get only 2-6Mbps of Internet download speed, but when I disconnect from Wi-Fi (local connection), Internet speed bumps up to the maximum of my home bandwidth (120Mbps).

Thanks! :)

EDIT 1 - `route`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.7.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp61s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp62s0
192.168.6.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp62s0
192.168.7.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp61s0
224.0.0.0       *               240.0.0.0       U     100    0        0 enp61s0
224.0.0.0       *               240.0.0.0       U     600    0        0 wlp62s0
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using, and can you append your question with the output of `route`

Comment: I'm using latest Linux Mint actually right now. But I'm also asking the same question for latest Ubuntu too. I've also added output from route too EDIT 1 in my post.

Comment: I think that the routes that you have defined manually are causing you some issues.  If looks like your default rute is set to use the Ethernet card, and the network 192.168.6.x in set to use the wireless card, but the routes to 224.x.x.x seem to have no real point in your system.

Comment: I have these settings from my other laptop that I've configured quite time ago by settings I've found on some forum. But, what you suggest how to configure route? Thanks! :)

Comment: I'd just remove them (and reboot) - your default route to the ethernet card should handle all the internet traffic, and the entry for 192.168.6.x should pick up all traffic directed at the wireless card.

Comment: @CharlesGreen
So I should just remove them for both Ethernet and WiFi configs?

Like this?
https://i.imgur.com/lW14AjV.png

Comment: Yes - you can always add them back if you have a specific need!  But the route is attempting to direct traffic destined to the network 224.x.x.x to a specific interface, and not really telling the routing tables where exactly the interface is.

Comment: @CharlesGreen , I've removed all routes and rebooted. Now when I connect to both networks I can't go to the Internet. Hm?

Comment: That's a little odd.  There is some information about default gateays for Mint at [this link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24141723/How-do-I-add-default-gateway-in-Linux-Mint.html)

Comment: @CharlesGreen ok, tested again and it works now. But I'm still not getting full bandwidth. Is unicast causing this? Hogging the network? How to fix this? Tried enabling IGMP on both routers but it seems it doesn't change anything...

Comment: This has some tips on generic settings if you're using 2 adapters and don't need highly specific routing: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165664/how-to-configure-ubuntu-to-access-internet-only-with-wifi-ignoring-wire-connecti