# Share WiFi via Ethernet

Tags: networking, ssh, xubuntu, internet

**Context**: the workstation is correctly connected to internet using its WiFi. An embedded system is connected to the same workstation (I can access the embedded system using ssh).

**Question**:
Is there a method for sharing the WiFi connection using an Eth connection in Xubuntu 18.04 LTS? The purpose is to have access to the internet using the system itself (for example, I would like to execute `apt-get install ...`).

[Here](https://www.cesariogarcia.com/?p=611), I have found the solution using gnome and not xcf. Thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same answer in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165664/how-to-configure-ubuntu-to-access-internet-only-with-wifi-ignoring-wire-connecti/1231851#1231851). However, it answers exactly the question on this page. Here the full text and solution:

Another wonderful solution (unfortunately not considered in the beginning) consists of creating an ethernet connection so that the internet access through the wifi is also shared with the embedded system. The solution is very easy to be implemented (and further details can be found surfing on the web, [here for an example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet)):

1. open **Edit connection...**
2. create (or open the existing) **Wire connection**
3. in the *IPv4 Settings tab*, select Method: **Shared to other computers**. This is the main difference with the other solutions for this answer:

[image]

Nothing more should be done in the "server part" (i.e., the workstation). You will see that the computer creates its own network. Click on **Connection Information** to see it or, from the command line, type `ifconfig` and look the take note of the address, sub-mask, and the other parameters for the ethernet connection (for example under `eth0` in my case).

The embedded system (for example a raspberry PI connected with the eth cable) should use the just-create network, using the parameter that you have just observed.

**CONCLUSION**: that way, you will be able to access the system (using `ssh` or what you want) and, at the same time, have free access to the web (in case you need to download new packets or programs).